# Favor one communication (chan) in select

Tags: go, select, channel

I know that if there are more than one "communications" that can proceed in a `select` statement that one is chosen randomly. I am trying to find an alternative approach that can prefer one "communication" over another.

The background is that I am sending values in a go-routine on a channel which is killed using a context.  When I kill it I want the channel to be immediately closed but currently the code will sometimes send a final value on the chan before closing it.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
   ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
   ch := make(chan int)

   go func() {
      defer close(ch)
      for i := 1; ; i++ {
         select {
         case <-ctx.Done():
            return
         case ch <- i:
         }
      }
   }()

   print(<-ch)
   print(<-ch)
   cancel()
   print(<-ch)
   print(<-ch)
```

This sometimes prints 1200 but usually 1230.  [Try it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_GC6SOxLIBG)

Are there any ideas on how to reorganise the code to favour the first case?  (Ie have it always print 1200.)

Comment: This is pretty unusual code. Normally you would not receive from ch after cancelling the context. And you have no reason to expect any particular values to be printed here anyway. This isn't a useful approximation of the real code, I think.

Comment: @Peter, this somewhat resembles the situation with `Timer.Reset()`

Comment: @BurakSerdar "Reset should be invoked only on stopped or expired timers with drained channels." from time.Timer.Reset documents.

Comment: @Peter, I believe it is actually a good approx. of the real code.  Actually you currently *must* keep reading from the `chan` after calling `cancel()` otherwise the goroutine writing to it _may_ block and never exit.  BTW I would prefer not to have to read the chan after canceling, which is the whole point of this question.

Comment: No, the goroutine will not block, because the ctx.Done() case becomes available.

Comment: I assume select prefers case with writing to channel because main goroutine is reading from it. You can add another select prior to the one in example to make sure context is processed first https://play.golang.org/p/H1U1D8GpBuT

Comment: @Peter said `the goroutine will not block ...` Thanks @Peter you are right.  My main worry was a goroutine leak but I can see now that this is not possible, so I think the solution is **no change needed** to my original code.

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible because `cancel()` is not a blocking operation in the main goroutine. Because of this, when `select` unblocks there can be multiple cases available and there is no way to favor one channel over the other. Any kind of check-channel-then-write scheme will be racy because the context can be canceled after the check.

Using a `done` channel and writing to it instead of context cancellation will work because writing to a `done` channel will be a blocking operation for the main goroutine, and select will always have one active case.

Comment: Thanks Burak, I sort of understood your first paragraph already which is why I was asking for ideas on how to reorganise the code.  I'll try the done `chan` but I was hoping there was a way using a `context`.

Comment: I started writing the answer to this question as "This is how you do it..." which later turned into what we have above. As I think more about it, I am convinced there cannot be a way to do it using context cancellation because of the way `select` works, and because effects of `cancel()` are not immediately know to the goroutine (i.e. `cancel()` does not wake up the goroutine)

Answer (score -1):

Note that this is an updated answer as there were problems with the original.

As pointed out by others you cannot avoid a race condition without additional synchronisation.  You could use a Mutex but `sync.Cond` seems like a good fit.
In the code below the receiving goroutine signals that it has received the value from the chan.  It cancels the context before signaling (using `Cond.Signal`) and the sending goroutine waits for the signal.  This avoids the race condition since the context status is updated before it can be checked.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
ch := make(chan int)
cond := sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}) // *** new

go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    cond.L.Lock()                   // *** new
    defer cond.L.Unlock()           // *** new
    for i := 1; ; i++ {
        ch <- i                     // *** moved
        cond.Wait()                 // *** new
        if ctx.Err() != nil {       // *** changed
            return
        }
    }
}()

print(<-ch)
cond.Signal()                      // *** new
print(<-ch)
cond.Signal()                      // *** new
print(<-ch)
cancel()
cond.Signal()                      // *** new
print(<-ch)
cond.Signal()                      // *** new
```

This is the simplest way I can see that the receiving goroutine will not receive any more values on the channel after it has canceled the context.

Try it on the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/le4xkq3N_2z)

Comment: This will not work, context can be canceled while waiting to write to the channel.

Comment: This is "better" as 1200 is usually printed but as Burak says is not a solution - eg: add a sleep before the cancel https://play.golang.org/p/T6fEX2ZGCHJ

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added an explanation and fixed the code to achieve what the OP was trying to do.